# How to operator overload fstream in a new class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, fstream

I want to wrap a new class to generate a file and make some auto resource recycle and some additional operate with the new file.
So I make a new class like

```
class TmpFile {
private:
    std::string tmp_file_name;
    std::ofstream tmp_file;

public:
    TmpFile(const std::string &name) :tmp_file_name(name),
                                       tmp_file(tmp_file_name, ios::out | ios::trunc) {}
    ~TmpFile() {
        tmp_file.close();
        //some operate afterwards using tmp_file
        ...
    }
};
```

But is there a way to operator overload "<<" to write into file inside "class TmpFile" like

```
TmpFile f;
f << "asd";
```

Comment: `void operator<<(const std::string& str) { }`

Comment: You do it same way(s) as with all other binary operators. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for all the gritty details.

Comment: see https://godbolt.org/z/7zc5c8TWr

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept only one object with "<<" operator, you can directly override it:

```
class TmpFile {
private:
    std::string tmp_file_name;
    std::ofstream tmp_file;

public:
    TmpFile(const std::string &name) :tmp_file_name(name),
                                       tmp_file(tmp_file_name, ios::out | ios::trunc) {}
    ~TmpFile() {
        tmp_file.close();
        //some operate afterwards using tmp_file
        ...
    }

    // here define your operator
    void operator << (const std::string& str) {
        // do something
    }
};
```

If you want to accept multiple object with a single operator << , you can check [how Eigen library implement like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523119/how-could-comma-separated-initialization-such-as-in-eigen-be-possibly-implemente), for example:

```
f << "asdf", "efsjkfl"
```